# Spring boot custom user with authentication

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security

I'm trying to do custom user with the properties I want and to use authentication , the CustomUser extends the spring User , The user is returned by the CustomProvider which implements UsersDetailsService

```
@Service
@Qualifier("UserDetailsService")
public class CustomUserDetailsService implements UserDetailsService {

    @Autowired
    private UserRepository userRepository;

    @Override
    @Transactional
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String email) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
        User user=userRepository.findByEmail(email);
        return new CustomUser(user.getName(),user.getPassword(),buildUserAuthority(user.getRoles()));
    }

    private List<GrantedAuthority> buildUserAuthority(Set<Role> userRoles) {

        Set<GrantedAuthority> setAuths = new HashSet<GrantedAuthority>();

        // add user's authorities
        for (Role userRole : userRoles) {
            setAuths.add(new SimpleGrantedAuthority(userRole.getRole()));
        }

        List<GrantedAuthority> Result = new ArrayList<GrantedAuthority>(setAuths);

        return Result;
    }


    @Getter
@Setter
public class CustomUser extends User {

    public CustomUser(String username, String password, Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> authorities) {
        super(username, password, authorities);
    }

    public String firstName;
    public String lastName;
}


@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
 @Autowired
    @Qualifier("UserDetailsService")
    private UserDetailsService customUserDetailsService;


    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth)
            throws Exception {
     /*   auth.
                jdbcAuthentication()
                .usersByUsernameQuery(usersQuery)
                .authoritiesByUsernameQuery(rolesQuery)
                .dataSource(dataSource)
                .passwordEncoder(bCryptPasswordEncoder);
*/
        auth.userDetailsService(customUserDetailsService);
    }
}
```

I have 2 issues :

1- I have commented the auth.jdbcAuthentication as I couldn't have the authentication and customProvider to work together, how can I use the database authentication with customuser ?

2- if I comment the jdbcAuthentication the customuser works but when I get the principal the password is null : authentication.getPrincipal().getPassword()

---

**Update :**

I have solved 2 by eraseCredentials(false) but still unable to do both ( authentication with custom user )

Answer (score 0):

Old answer:

I have solved it by this :

```
auth.eraseCredentials(false).userDetailsService(customUserDetailsService).and().jdbcAuthentication()
                .usersByUsernameQuery(usersQuery)
                .authoritiesByUsernameQuery(rolesQuery)
                .dataSource(dataSource)
                .passwordEncoder(bCryptPasswordEncoder);
```

---

update:

I found that no need to use 2 types of authentication as spring will verify the password with the returned user.